# React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I am new to Jest and JavaScript in general. I have got a written js code that include some components and I need to add a Log Out option for this website.

I have a Log Out component but I am not sure how to add it to the js code.

This is the Log Out component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class LogoutButton extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.context.store.dispatch(logout());
  };

  render() {
    return <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Logout</button>;
  }
}
```

And this is my WholeScreen Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Nav, NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {YearlySummary} from './YearlySummaryComponent.js'


export class WholeScreen  extends Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      year: (new Date()).getFullYear()
    };

    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  } 
  handleSelect(eventKey){    
    this.setState({year : eventKey})

  }


  render(){
    <LogoutButton />
    var buttons = [];
    var yearData = [];
    if (this.state.year === (new Date()).getFullYear() ){
      buttons.push(<NavItem key={this.state.year - 1} eventKey={this.state.year - 1} >&larr;{this.state.year - 1}</NavItem>);

    }
    else{
      buttons.push(<NavItem key={this.state.year - 1} eventKey={this.state.year - 1} >&larr;{this.state.year - 1}</NavItem>);
      buttons.push(<NavItem key={this.state.year + 1} eventKey={this.state.year + 1} >{this.state.year + 1}&rarr;</NavItem>);
    }

    var thisYear = this.state.year;
    this.props.data.forEach(function(dataEntry) {
      var dt = new Date(dataEntry.donationDate);
   //    var dtUTC = new Date(dt.getUTCFullYear(),dt.getUTCMonth(),dt.getUTCDate(),dt.getUTCHours(),dt.getUTCMinutes(),dt.getUTCSeconds());
       if (dt.getUTCFullYear() === thisYear){ 

         //dataEntry.donationDate = dtUTC.getMonth().toString()+"/"+dtUTC.getDate().toString()+"/"+dtUTC.getFullYear().toString();
        yearData.push(dataEntry);
       }      
     });


    return(
      <div className="WholeScreen">
        <div>
       <Nav bsStyle="pills" activeKey={this.state.year} onSelect={this.handleSelect} >
          {buttons}
        </Nav>
        </div>
        <div>          
          <YearlySummary year={this.state.year} yearData={yearData}/>
        </div>
      </div> 
    );
  }

}
```

When I add it and then run

```
npm run buid
```

I get an error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/LogoutButtonComponent.js
  Line 10:  'logout' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

My question is how do I add the LogOut component to the WholeScreen component such that it sill compile?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can export the LogoutButton component by default so you don't need use the curly braces. If you don't export another thing from file, use `export default class ClassName`. That's better.

```
import LogoutButton from './LogoutButtonComponent.js'
```

and now you can put that wherever you want to show,

```
<LogoutButton />
```

Comment: Thanks, I am a bit confused now. In my case should I use the brackets or not ?

Comment: Thank you! Please read my last comment to @Think-Twice above and I will appreciate if you would share with me your solution for this situation.

Comment: Ah ok, where is your logout function? The error about the this line: `this.context.store.dispatch(logout());` It can't find the logout function. And secondly, add the `<LogoutButton />` to return in the render function. Not to head of render function.

Answer (score 0):

Since your LogoutButton is not default export you can import it like below

```
 import { LogoutButton } from './LogoutButtonComponent.js';
```

If it is default export then component can be imported like below,

```
 import LogoutButton from './LogoutButtonComponent.js';
```

In your case import it like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Nav, NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {YearlySummary} from './YearlySummaryComponent.js'
import { LogoutButton } from './LogoutButtonComponent.js';

export class WholeScreen  extends Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      year: (new Date()).getFullYear()
    };

    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  } 
  handleSelect(eventKey){    
    this.setState({year : eventKey})

  }


  render(){

    var buttons = [];
    var yearData = [];
    if (this.state.year === (new Date()).getFullYear() ){
      buttons.push(<NavItem key={this.state.year - 1} eventKey={this.state.year - 1} >&larr;{this.state.year - 1}</NavItem>);

    }
    else{
      buttons.push(<NavItem key={this.state.year - 1} eventKey={this.state.year - 1} >&larr;{this.state.year - 1}</NavItem>);
      buttons.push(<NavItem key={this.state.year + 1} eventKey={this.state.year + 1} >{this.state.year + 1}&rarr;</NavItem>);
    }

    var thisYear = this.state.year;
    this.props.data.forEach(function(dataEntry) {
      var dt = new Date(dataEntry.donationDate);
   //    var dtUTC = new Date(dt.getUTCFullYear(),dt.getUTCMonth(),dt.getUTCDate(),dt.getUTCHours(),dt.getUTCMinutes(),dt.getUTCSeconds());
       if (dt.getUTCFullYear() === thisYear){ 

         //dataEntry.donationDate = dtUTC.getMonth().toString()+"/"+dtUTC.getDate().toString()+"/"+dtUTC.getFullYear().toString();
        yearData.push(dataEntry);
       }      
     });


    return(
      <div className="WholeScreen">
        <div>
       <Nav bsStyle="pills" activeKey={this.state.year} onSelect={this.handleSelect} >
          {buttons}
          <LogoutButton />
        </Nav>
        </div>
        <div>          
          <YearlySummary year={this.state.year} yearData={yearData}/>
        </div>
      </div> 
    );
  }

}
```

logout is not defined because logout function isn't defined check my comments in the code below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class LogoutButton extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    //this.context.store.dispatch(logout()); //here you are calling logout() but this never defined in this component. You need to define logout function as you are calling
  };

  render() {
    return <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Logout</button>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But after I import it, where and what exactly should I add to the Whole Screen component ? or maybe I should add something to App.js ?

Comment: It depends on where you want to show LogoutButton you can just call <LogoutButton /> in Whole Screen component render

Comment: I see. I added it as you said, but when I run npm run build, I get a compilation error. I edited my question so you can see the error. Note that I added <LogoutButton /> under render() function in the WholeScreenComponent. Also, in that case both { LogoutButton } and LogoutButton does not work. Thanks!

Comment: You are calling logout in Logout button component but logout function is not defined. So define it and the call that if required

Comment: Thank you @Think-Twice . I sorry but as I am totally new into this world; The logout() function should be written inside LogOutButtonComponent ? if so, would you mind please to give me an example of how this code should be written? Thank you!

Comment: If you don't no what you want to do with logout then why do you need that function you can remove that

Comment: All I want to do is to add a log out button to the website. I not sure what do you mean. Should I remove the logout() call ?

Comment: If that is the case then comment this line //this.context.store.dispatch(logout()); I updated my answer please check